# Oracle SQL Developer VJDBC connector

Tags: jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to add a new connection into Oracle SQL Developer using JDBC.

Here is my VJDBC URL: `jdbc:vjdbc:servlet:https://company.plateau.com/vjdbc/vjdbc,db10g`

Connection is not working at the moment. Do you know if there is something else to configure?

Thank you for your help,
Damien

Comment: "not working" doesn't tell us anything, please share details as to how it is not working.

Comment: Hi Mark. When trying to add the connector, I get an error message in French: "Statut : échec -Echec du test : Informations de connexion non valides entrées. Vérifiez le format d'URL du pilote spécifié.". basically it saids that connection information are incorrect and that I should check the URL format for this driver.